# How to convert table row data into multiple rows for mobile resolution while using ng-repeat in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

am new to angular JS.
I have some data like

```
var aUsers=[{'name':'sachin','runs':20000},{'name':'dravid','runs':15000},{'name':'ganguly','runs':18000}]
```

i display the data in the table using ng-repeat.

```
<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Runs</th></tr> <tr ng-repeat="obj in aUsers"> <td>{{obj.name}}</td> <td>{{obj.runs}}</td></tr></table>
```

then output like below

```
Name    Runs
Sachin  20000
Dravid  15000
Ganguly 18000
```

But my requirement is if my resolution is mobile then that time my view should be like below

```
Name  sachin
Runs  20000
Name  Dravid
Runs  15000
Name  Ganguly
Runs  18000
```

am using bootstrap

Please help me to go forward.

thanks,Srinivasa Rao.CH

Answer (score 0):

You can use col classes instead of table

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="obj in aUsers">
  <div class="col-sm-6">{{obj.name}}</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">{{obj.runs}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put both values in the same `<td>`?

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="obj in aUsers"> 
    <td>
      <div class="title">Name</div>
      <div class="value">{{obj.name}}</div>
      <br/>
      <div class="title">Runs</div>
      <div class="value">{{obj.runs}}</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```